# How to run mozilla hubs on my local machine?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, mozilla, virtual-reality, webvr

I've been trying to run mozilla hubs locally because I want to customize it. But the problem is, the documentation includes the deployment on aws and digital ocean.

Later I cloned https://github.com/mozilla/hubs - the hubs client
and also cloned https://github.com/mozilla/reticulum - the reticulum server

I followed the exact same instructions as mentioned. Correct me if I'm wrong.

When running the client alone :
1. Cloned the client https://github.com/mozilla/hubs
2. Installed the dependencies using npm ci
3. npm run dev runs the client locally.
4. Clicking on scene editor gives me this 'Cannot GET /spoke'

When running it with the reticulum server:
1. I followed the same steps as mentioned in https://github.com/mozilla/reticulum
2. Installed all the dependencies PostgreSQL and Elixir+Phoenix
3. mix deps.get (no error)
4. mix ecto.create (no error as I already changed the password)
5. From the assets directory, npm install
6. From the project directory mkdir -p storage/dev
7. Started the server using iex -S mix phx.server
8. Mapped hubs.local to 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts file
9. Started the client https://github.com/mozilla/hubs by npm run local
10. As per the instruction, when I navigate to https://hubs.local:4000?skipadmin, I get error on the server terminal, and the browser screen as well. I am attaching it below.
[Error image on server terminal and and browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubJoB.png)

Please help me resolve this issue. If I am doing something wrong, please let me know and tell me how can I run mozilla hubs locally to make some modifications.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Its weird that hubs works only on aws

Comment: Also looking into this, I have found that there is an issue started on GH tracking this, although no response from the team or other expert: https://github.com/mozilla/reticulum/issues/423

Comment: I'm not working on this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a bit late, and maybe you've been already through this but in case anyone want to try it further :
Did you try to skip the admin step by opening https://hubs.local:8080 and then use the email trick you can pick up from the running reticulum?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).